# Can't Uninstall Tor Browser

Tags: uninstall, tor-browser

I recently tried uninstalling the Tor browser by following the instructions provided [from a website](https://howtoinstall.co/en/tor?action=uninstall), but Tor does not seem to be uninstalling properly. Whenever I search for Tor in the Launcher, I still see an entry for it without an icon:

[image: Tor is showing up, but without an icon]

What do I need to do to fully uninstall Tor?

Comment: What happens (what error message do you get) when you try to perform the uninstall command? Your screenshot is not related to the problem.

Comment: Do you remember how you installed tor?

Answer (score 7):

**1. Verify that the app is not anymore installed**

Double check it is not installed by the APT system by running `sudo apt purge tor` once more.

If `apt`  confirms it is not there, then search for remaining files from a possible manual installation. Search for a file with the name "start-tor-browser" on your system.

If such file exists, check the contents of the directory and delete it if it contains files of tor (including firefox, folders "browser", "defaults", "fonts", "icons")

If not, then

**2. Find and remove the orphanned launcher**

It may be the launcher only that is still residing on your system. Since the launcher calls "sh", the desktop still considers it a valid desktop file.

Search the launcher with the command

```
find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Name=Tor Browser" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

and delete the file (or move it away).